# Redshift SQL result set 100s of rows wide efficiency (long to wide)

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

**Scenario**:  Medical records reporting to state government which requires a pipe delimited text file as input.

**Challenge**:  Select hundreds of values from a fact table and produce a wide result set to be (Redshift) UNLOADed to disk.

**What I have tried so far** is a SQL that I want to make into a VIEW.

```
;WITH 
CTE_patient_record AS 
(
 SELECT 
   record_id 
 FROM fact_patient_record
 WHERE update_date = <yesterday>
)
,CTE_patient_record_item AS
(
 SELECT 
    record_id
   ,record_item_name
   ,record_item_value
 FROM fact_patient_record_item fpri
 INNER JOIN CTE_patient_record cpr ON fpri.record_id = cpr.record_id
)
```

Note that fact_patient_record has 87M rows and fact_patient_record_item has 97M rows.
The above code runs in 2 seconds for 2 test records and the CTE_patient_record_item CTE has about 200 rows per record for a total of about 400.

Now, produce the result set:

```
,CTE_result AS 
(
  SELECT 
     cpr.record_id
    ,cpri002.record_item_value AS diagnosis_1
    ,cpri003.record_item_value AS diagnosis_2
    ,cpri004.record_item_value AS medication_1
    ... 

  FROM CTE_patient_record cpr
  INNER JOIN CTE_patient_record_item cpri002 ON cpr.cpr.record_id = cpri002.cpr.record_id 
             AND cpri002.record_item_name = 'diagnosis_1'
  INNER JOIN CTE_patient_record_item cpri003 ON cpr.cpr.record_id = cpri003.cpr.record_id 
             AND cpri003.record_item_name = 'diagnosis_2'
  INNER JOIN CTE_patient_record_item cpri004 ON cpr.cpr.record_id = cpri004.cpr.record_id 
             AND cpri003.record_item_name = 'mediation_1'
  ...

) SELECT * FROM CTE_result
```

Result set looks like this:

```
record_id diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 medication_1 ...
100001             09          9B          88X ...
```

...and then I use the Reshift UNLOAD command to write to disk pipe delimited.

I am testing this on a full production sized environment but only for 2 test records.
Those 2 test records have about 200 items each.
Processing output is 2 rows 200 columns wide.

**It takes 30 to 40 minutes to process just just the 2 records.**

You might ask me why I am joining on the item name which is a string.  Basically there is no item id, no integer, to join on.  Long story.

I am looking for suggestions on how to improve performance.  With only 2 records, 30 to 40 minutes is unacceptable.  What will happen when I have 1000s of records?

**I have also tried** making the VIEW a MATERIALIZED VIEW however, it takes 30 to 40 minutes (not surprisingly) to compile the materialized view also.

I am not sure which route to take from here.

1. Stored procedure?  I have experience with stored procs.
2. Create new tables so I can create integer id's to join on and indexes? However, my managers are "new table" averse.
3. ?

I could just stop with the first two CTEs, pull the data down to **python** and process using **pandas dataframe** which I've done before successfully but it would be nice if I could have an efficient query, just use Redshift UNLOAD and be done with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**:  Many thanks to Paul Coulson and Bill Weiner for pointing me in the right direction!  (Paul I am unable to upvote your answer as I am too new here).

Using (pseudo code):

```
MAX(CASE WHEN t1.name = 'somename' THEN t1.value END ) AS name
...
FROM table1 t1
```

reduced execution time from 30 minutes to 30 seconds.
EXPLAIN PLAN for the original solution is 2700 lines long, for the new solution using conditional aggregation is 40 lines long.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Use conditional aggregation instead

Comment: @PhilCoulson so you are suggesting 200 CASE statements with a single JOIN?

Comment: You could use dynamic pivot if your db supports it,  but 200 conditional aggregations with one join should perform better than 200 joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some more information it is impossible to know what is going on for sure but what you are doing is likely not ideal.  An explanation plan and the execution time per step would help a bunch.

What I suspect is getting you is that you are reading a 97M row table 200 times.  This will slow things down but shouldn't take 40 min.  So I also suspect that record_item_name is not unique per value of record_id.  This will lead to row replication and could be expanding the data set many fold. Also is record_id unique in fact_patient_record? If not then this will cause row replication. If all of this is large enough to cause significant spill and significant network broadcasting your 40 min execution time is very plausible.

There is no need to be joining when all the data is in a single copy of the table.  @PhilCoulson is correct that some sort of conditional aggregation could be applied and the decode() syntax could save you space if you don't like case.  Several of the above issues that might be affecting your joins would also make this aggregation complicated.  What are you looking for if there are several values for record_item_value for each record_id and record_item_name pair?  I expect you have some discovery of what your data holds in your future.

Comment: I am only scanning the 97M item table once and storing the items relevant to the 2 records in "CTE_patient_record_item".  Also, "record_item_name" is unique to the record.  For example, the "record_item_name" "diagnosis_1" appears only once in the data per record_id.  Also "record_id" is unique on "fact_patient_record".  I am JOINing on the CTE which contains about 400 rows where all 400 are unique "record_id" + "record_item_name" + "record_item_value" combinations i.e. that combo of those 3 fields *could* be used as a composite primary key (if I was building a table).

Comment: Every time you list a table, even the same table, in the FROM clause it will be scanned AFAIK.  Check stl_scan for your query.  It is true that RS will only scan the columns that you specify but record_id, record_item_value, and record_item_name are needed each time it is scanned.  Putting the table in a CTE doesn't create a "reused" data element, sorry.  If you want this you need to create a temp table and use that but this temp table will be scanned 200 times.  Also you are not joining on unique combinations of 3 columns, but rather 2.  Check your EXPLAIN plan